# Materialize buttons not working

Tags: html, materialize

I have a problem with materialize buttons/links. There is href written though when trying to press it it does not go to the webpage.

```html
<a href="www.google.com" id="download-button" class="btn-small waves-effect waves-light pink lighten-4">button </a>
```

Comment: As it is written, it's a relative link, so if you're on the front page of `example.com`, it will navigate to `example.com/www.google.com`. To make it absolute, enter the full URL in the `href` attribute including the protocol (or at least `//`), i.e. `https://www.google.com`. Consider reading a HTML basics tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Mention http:// at the start or else it will consider url to be a part of existing host and will be appended to the current domain

```html
<a href="http://www.google.com" id="download-button" class="btn-small waves-effect waves-light pink lighten-4">button </a>
```